# Gridview and Cardview disappears on physical device for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, xml, android-layout

The layout works well with all types of emulators but when working with physical devices the Gridview Disappears.

I want to make the gridview visible for all types of physical devices.I have tried with many physical devices but only samsung grand prime shows the gridview. The gridview or probably the card view disappears on all other physical devices with slightly bigger screen sizes.
Plz Help code is given below

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:background="#808080"
>     android:layout_weight="2"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="1dp">
>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/MyTextView"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:fontFamily="cursive"
>         android:text="Women's Beauty"
>         android:textColor="#ffffff"
>         android:textSize="40sp"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> <GridLayout
>     android:columnCount="2"
>     android:rowCount="3"
>     android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
>     android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="8"
>     android:padding="14dp"
>     >
>
>     <!-- Need a Library Here Card View -->
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>
>         android:id="@+id/cdv1"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>         app:cardElevation="9dp">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>             android:layout_margin="16dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             >
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Clothing"
>                 android:textAlignment="center"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"
>                 />
>             <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:src="@drawable/clothing"/>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>
>         android:id="@+id/cdv2"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>         app:cardElevation="8dp">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>             android:layout_margin="16dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             >
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Shoes"
>                 android:textAlignment="center"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"
>                 />
>             <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:src="@drawable/highheel"/>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>
>         android:id="@+id/cdv3"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>         app:cardElevation="8dp">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>             android:layout_margin="16dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             >
>
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Makeup"
>                 android:textAlignment="center"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"
>                 />
>             <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:src="@drawable/makeup"/>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>
>         android:id="@+id/cdv4"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>         app:cardElevation="8dp">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>             android:layout_margin="16dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             >
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Health"
>                 android:textAlignment="center"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"
>                 />
>             <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:src="@drawable/health"/>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>
>         android:id="@+id/cdv5"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>         app:cardElevation="8dp">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>             android:layout_margin="16dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             >
>
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Facial"
>                 android:textAlignment="center"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"
>                 />
>             <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:src="@drawable/facial"/>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>
>         android:id="@+id/cdv6"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_columnWeight="1"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:layout_rowWeight="1"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
>         app:cardElevation="8dp">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>             android:layout_margin="16dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             >
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textView"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Hair Styles"
>                 android:textAlignment="center"
>                 android:textColor="#000000"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 android:src="@drawable/hairstyle"/>
>
>
>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> </GridLayout>
> ```

Here are screen shoots

```
                           ON Emulator
```

[image]

```
                            ON Physical Device
```

[image]

Comment: Please share stack trace if some exception happens.

Comment: 02-03 23:55:16.946 1313-1313/? I/zygote: option[2]=-Xstacktracefile:/data/anr/traces.txt
02-03 23:56:01.880 1684-1684/? I//system/bin/webview_zygote32: option[2]=-Xstacktracefile:/data/anr/traces.txt